# "Department" user field not accessible through the API?

Tags: api, rally

We have set up the available departments for our workspace and were hoping to migrate an existing Excel document with user:department relationships over to the new data fields. I wrote a Python script using the Pyral package that attempts to do this, but it looks like the "Department" field is not accessible via the API? Is this intended or could there be a problem with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyral defaults to Webservices API (WSAPI) 1.37, and the new User fields are only present on WSAPI >= 1.41.

You can override pyral's default WSAPI version by changing this variable:

`WS_API_VERSION = "1.37"`

in pyral's config.py to:

`WS_API_VERSION = "1.42"`